# tablejoin in qgis 2.x adds name of table to columnheader attributetable

Tags: attribute-joins, qgis-2

When joining a table to a shapefile through 'layer properties > joins' the columnheader of the attributetable shows the name of the file you joined.

eg.:
the name of the table is: STAVAZA3

the table looks like:

[image]

after joining with a shapefile, the attributetable looks like:

[image]

This didn't happen in qgis 1.8.x.

Predefined legends wouldn't work anymore because of the changed names of the columns.

Is this the standard way how qgis 2.x joins tables?  Or is it due to a property that i have to set anywhere?

Comment: I think you should ask this in the QGIS User mailing list or even reporting a bug.

Comment: **To those intending to reply:** Because this question is a duplicate (as pointed out by @MappaGnosis) and has already been answered in the duplicate thread, then when it becomes available for closure it will be closed and (if possible) all answers will be merged with those to the duplicate question. Please frame your answers so that they will continue to make sense in the context of the duplicate question.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the duplicate.  I didn't find it before.I agree ilaria marengo that it would be nice to have the choice not to rename the column headers each time I joined an xls-table to my shapefile.

Comment: I figured out how to do it.  Look in the question as mentioned above.